# Custom AlertDialog with custom listview in android

Tags: android, listview, customdialog

I would like to know how can I listener when user clicks on custom listview in a custom AlertDialog. I would like to show the list of credit cards with 2 textviews and 2 buttons in order to add one credit card or cancel the transaction.

I can`t listen this events anyway.

I have this

```
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.popup_select_creditcard, null);
        lvCreditCards = (ListView) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.lvCreditCards);

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                context);
        try {

            List itemsCreditCard = new ArrayList();

            JSONObject json = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < creditCards.length(); i++) {
                json = null;
                json = creditCards.getJSONObject(i);
                itemsCreditCard.add(new ItemCreditCards(json.getString("four_numbers"), json.getString("cad"),
                        json.getString("stripe_token"), false));


            }
            lvCreditCards.setItemsCanFocus(false);
            lvCreditCards.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position,
                                        long arg3) {
                    ItemCreditCards item = (ItemCreditCards) lvCreditCards.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                    //Si el ultimo valor (stripeToken) es string 0, es que se está comprando un evento sin pago telemático
                    APIXceed.purchaseRSVP(eventId, rsvpSelected, String.valueOf(Entradas), item.getStripeToken());
                }
            });

            }catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);
        alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(true);

        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(App.getContext().getString(R.string.select_credit_card));
        alertDialogBuilder
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.add_credit_card, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, AddCreditCardActivity.class);
                        myIntent.putExtra("ParentClassName", "Event");

                        context.startActivity(myIntent);

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.Cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // User cancelled the dialog
                        alertDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

        // create alert dialog
        alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

        // show it
        alertDialog.show();
```

As you can see, I have lvCreditCards.setOnItemClickListener, but it doesn't do anything :-( And I can't put a simple adapter directly on this alertDialog. I have 2 or 3 data to show in each row of this listview.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: It seems you're trying to put an Adapter to the ListView, like what I have done. Do you want to do this? Unfortunately your code needs some re-structuring.